# Leading tabs in pasted tables - MS Word for Mac version 15.18

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I am pasting tables into a doc created in MS Word for Mac version 15.18.

I am using either the keyboard shortcut or "paste using destination styles".

Whichever method, in every cell I get leading tabs which I have to then delete by hand.

N.B. These tabs are not in the destination table style as far as I can see. Unless there is some kind of hidden default in Excel, there are no leading tabs in the source table.

Anyone know:

1. Where the tabs are coming from?
2. How to switch them off?

I tried e.g. changing the cell format in Excel to "Text" but no change.

Comment: Does your data contain any desirable tabs? If not, you could just copy the character and remove it with a find and replace.

Comment: I tried a number of variations on this but could not see this behaviour, so just wondering whether your system needs repairs and/or Office re-install (considering how frequently the 2016 updates are coming I would guess even an "update Office" might have the desired effect - it certainly fixed a different, but similar kind of problem I had a few weeks ago).

Answer (score 0):

Tabs is in MS Word Home Tab, Paragraph Group click on the arrow near Paragraph then Tabs and clear all
maybe the table you are copying contains Tabs spacing

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's a start - but I have no tabs in my Excel source table.